# How to connect a view file inside the sub folder of view folder in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I am having subfolder named 'auth' inside the view folder, and i am having a controller named 'job' i am having some files inside "auth" folder where i have to call in some form actions and also for some validations like the users are already login, email verifications etc etc....

I am new to codeigniter so please help.me how i can connect the files which is inside a "auth" folder to forms and various validations

I also tried by $this->load->view('auth/login') but not working, is there anything i have to do

Please reply with explanations as i am doing a project it will help.me in future projects

Comment: post the view folder structure and the codes you are using.

Comment: And explain the "..not working" part well. Are you getting any kind of errors ? or a blank page ? or anything else ?

Comment: please specify your code to load view

Comment: sorry it is working now thanks for your comments, i made a mistake in the url. i didnt change the mod_rewrite, now i is working fine